# Unseen Indent in python

Tags: python, indentation

I'm working with Numeca/Design3D. I have to couple 2 rows, an Impeller and diffuser via a python script. This script is rewritten for many samples used for optimizing. This part of the script:

```
def multistage_script_assembly(row1_mesh , row2_mesh , multistage_mesh):
    import_igg_project("/home/slagter/Desktop/Optimization/Impeller_Turbo_Comp/Impeller_Turbo_Comp_DATA_Impeller_222/_dbs/multistage/ImpAnchorRough.igg","row1")
    import_igg_project("/home/slagter/Desktop/Optimization/Impeller_Turbo_Comp/Impeller_Turbo_Comp_DATA_Impeller_222/_dbs/multistage/DiffWholeMeshRough.igg","row2")
    patch("row2#row_2_flux_1_Main_Blade_skin",6,3).set_type("ROT")
.
.
.
```

Is rewritten to look like:

```
def multistage_script_assembly(row1_mesh , row2_mesh , multistage_mesh):
import_igg_project("/home/slagter/Desktop/Optimization/Impeller_Turbo_Comp/Impeller_Turbo_Comp_DATA_Impeller_222/_dbs/_flow_1/_mesh/ImpAnchorRough.igg","row1")
import_igg_project("/home/slagter/Desktop/Optimization/Impeller_Turbo_Comp/Impeller_Turbo_Comp_DATA_Impeller_222/_dbs/_mesh/DiffWholeMeshRough.igg","row2")
    patch("row2#row_2_flux_1_Main_Blade_skin",6,3).set_type("ROT")
.
.
.
```

Hence the indentation in front of import_igg_project is not seen and an error stating "indentation expected" pops up.

Any suggestions as to how I can force the indentation or solve this problem. It might as well be Numeca/Design3D that is faulty?

Comment: Although not clear on the question there is a 1 tab indentation in front of import_igg_project("....").

Answer (score 0):

See if there is a setting for use spaces instead of tabs in the tool - if there is use it, also check that the template you are using has **NO** tabs.
Otherwise if you are stuck with the tool then post process using replace('\t', '    ').